# Conveying "Give me a fish and I’ll eat for a day. Teach me to fish and I’ll eat for a lifetime."

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, proverbes

Is there a French equivalent of

"Give me a fish and I’ll eat for a day. Teach me to fish and I’ll eat for a lifetime."

?

I've seen one-to-one renderings but I'm wondering if it exists a French idiomatic expression or proverb.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very common translation of this quote attributed to Maimonides is this:

> Donne un poisson à un homme, il mangera un jour. Apprends-lui à pêcher, il mangera toute sa vie

Sources:
https://citations.ouest-france.fr/citation-maimonide/donne-poisson-homme-mangera-jour-103184.html
https://www.quotez.net/french/maimonide.htm

Comment: C'est aussi une formule connue en Belgique, où une ONG appelée "Iles de paix" fait un peu de ce proverbe son slogan. (https://www.ilesdepaix.org/qui-sommes-nous/ong-iles-de-paix/vision-et-missions/)

Answer (score 1):

> Il vaut mieux savoir faire soi-même que de toujours compter sur les autres.

Answer (score -5):

Are found in [Linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/give+a+man+a+fish+and+you+feed+him+for+a+day%2C+teach+a+man+to.html) nothing more than variants on the theme of  literal translation.
[reverso](https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-french/give+a+man+a+fish) does not provide anything better. It seems that there is nothing else.
As a literal translation I'd use this.

- Donner un poisson à un homme le nourrit pour la journée, lui apprendre à pêcher le nourrit pour la vie.

Comme il n'existe aucune forme établie, une nouvelle forme, en termes plus modernes, ne semble pas de trop et je propose donc celle-ci.

- Qui donne un repas par charité nourrit pour la journée, qui enseigne le moyen d'acquérir des repas nourrit pour la vie.